# Adding string characters to a for loop after converting int to string in c++

Tags: c++

So I'm busy with a school project and new to C++ and I'm a bit stuck, so here is the question:

When your program begins, it should prompt the user to enter an integer number greater than or equal to 1. This number should be assigned to a variable called control.
You must create a for loop that iterates a number of times equal to control. Each time it iterates, it must append a numeric digit to a string, with the first digit added being 1, and for each iteration, the next number is the previous number multiplied by the original number input. Additionally, the spaces that would ordinarily be between the numbers must instead be the ”#” symbol.
Once the loop is finished iterating, it must display the string that you have constructed.
As a hint, consider the use of string streams for converting between integer to string.

Examples of this program are below:

Please enter a number: 3

1#3#9

Please enter a number: 5

1#5#25#125#625

Please enter a number: 1

1

And here is my code so far :

```
int main()
{
    int control;
    int value;
    string final;
    int test;
    stringstream convert;

    cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> control;

    if (control >= 1)
    {
        value = 1;

        for (int count = 2; count <= control; count++)
        {
            value = value * control;           <---- SO IM STUCK HERE 
            convert << value;                        TRYING TO INSERT "#"
            final = convert.str() + "#";             BETWEEN THE VALUES
        }

        cout << "1#" << final << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid number!" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Adding `#` character to an integer will not do what you think it will. You should supply it to your string or stringstream.

Comment: You have the `stringstream`. Use it: `convert << '#' << value;` Just handle the case when ss is empty.

Comment: There's something very important that's missing from your question. That would be an actual question. The only thing I see here is a description of your homework assignment, and your code so far. That's fine, but what exactly is your question? "I'm a bit stuck" is not a specific question.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. feel like an idiot, I can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seemed to be a very simple fix, I feel like an idiot but thanks for the help.

Old code : convert << value;

New code : convert << '#' << value;